# How do I make the tilde encompass two variables?

Tags: tilde

I want to put a tilde above `$ \tilde{L_1}^{T}\omega_1 $` such that it encompasses these two variable. How do I do that? My approach here puts two separate \tilde on L_1 and the transpose T

```
$$\frac{\partial \text{T}{\partial C_{N1} } = \tilde{\tilde{L_1}^{T}\omega_1}$$
```

Comment: Please always post a complete document that shows the problem. If I try your fragment I get `Runaway argument?
{\partial \text {T}{\partial C_{N1} } = \tilde {\tilde {L_1}^{T}\omega \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \frac`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

`\widetilde` but do not use `$$` in LaTex and don't use `\text` for math variables as that picks up the current text font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\frac{\partial \mathrm{T}}{\partial C_{N1} } = \widetilde{\tilde{L_1}^{\!\mathrm{T}}\omega_1}
\]

\end{document}
```